# Set Maximum property of a Numeric Up Down Control to Decimal.MaxValue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, numericupdown

I have NumericUpDown control in windows forms. I want all its values to be greater than 1 up to the maximum value possible for that control. Since the [`Maximum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) property is of type decimal, and the maximum decimal value can be found in [`Decimal.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), is there a neat way to set the `Maximum` property value of the NumericUpDown control to `Decimal.MaxValue` in the properties window? I could copy the numeric value of `Decimal.MaxValue` and paste it into the properties window, but that won't be neat, if you know what I mean.

The property window does not allow setting the `Maximum` property to `Decimal.MaxValue` as it probably treats it as a string and throws a `Decimal.MaxValue is not a valid value for Decimal` error.

Comment: if the maximum value allowed is `Decimal.MaxValue` (you know this is a **gigantic** value, 2^32-1 is too tiny compared to this value), `NumericUpDown` does not suit your need. `NumericUpDown` is used to `count` countable things, like temperature, people, work hour, not values like 1.06575674897548*10E+21.

Comment: Try Binding it to a Decimal property

Comment: You can of course always assign it in *code*, in the form constructor after the InitializeComponent() call.  Or you can copy-paste this: `79228162514264337593543950335`